# Band Structure Calculation with HSE06 Hybrid Functional in VASP

Tags: vasp, band-structure, hse06

I am using HSE06 hybrid functional to calculate the band structure. I copied IBZKPT file as the KPOINTS file and pasted the k point path for the band structure after this file. The k point path for the band structure was obtained by another band structure calculation with PBE functional for the same system before. The new KPOINTS files is shown below.

```
Automatically generated mesh
61
Reciprocal lattice
0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 1
0.09090909090909 0.00000000000000 0.00000000000000 2
...
-0.09090909090909 0.45454545454546 0.00000000000000 2
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.000
...
0.50000000 0.50000000 0.00000000 0.000
```

The INCAR file is shown below.

```
ISTART = 1
LWAVE = .FALSE.
LCHARGE = .TRUE.
ICHARG = 11
IVDW = 12
ISPIN = 2
MAGMOM = 0.156 -0.155 -0.096 0.096 -0.156 0.155 -0.156 0.155 0.096\
-0.096 0.156 -0.155 -0.156 0.155 0.096 -0.096 0.156 -0.155\
0.156 -0.155 -0.096 0.096 -0.156 0.155
LORBIT = 11
ENCUT = 500
ISMEAR = 0
SIGMA = 0.03
PREC = Accurate
LHFCALC = .TRUE.
AEXX = 0.25
HFSCREEN = 0.2
ALGO = Damped
TIME = 0.4
PRECFOCK = Fast
ISYM = 3
LREAL = Auto
NELMIN = 5
NELM = 700
NELMDL = -10
EDIFF = 1e-5
NPAR = 32
KPAR= 16
```

After the NSCF calculation done, the band structure is completely wrong. I upload the band structure below, which I obtained through using p4v software to read vasprun.xml file from the non-self consistent calculation with the HSE06 hybrid functional.

[image]

The output file shows the warning information below.

```
| |
| W W AA RRRRR N N II N N GGGG !!! |
| W W A A R R NN N II NN N G G !!! |
| W W A A R R N N N II N N N G !!! |
| W WW W AAAAAA RRRRR N N N II N N N G GGG ! |
| WW WW A A R R N NN II N NN G G |
| W W A A R R N N II N N GGGG !!! |
| |
| Your generating k-point grid is not commensurate to the symmetry |
| of the lattice. This can cause slow convergence with respect |
| to k-points for HF type calculations |
| suggested SOLUTIONS: |
| ) if not already the case, use automatic k-point generation |
| ) shift your grid to Gamma (G) (e.g. required for hex or fcc lattice) |
| |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am doing the band structure calculation and I have to set up the k point path manually. I cannot use automatic k-point generation, which is used in single point calculation so I do not understand what VASP means by use automatic k-point generation in this band structure calculation step.

Would anyone please give me some suggestions on the solution?

Thank you very much.

Kieran

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "completely wrong"?

Comment: It seems you may have accidentally made a second account. If you want to merge these, follow the instructions from the help page: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 5):

As the error indicate:

```
| Your generating k-point grid is not commensurate to the symmetry |
| of the lattice. This can cause slow convergence with respect |
| to k-points for HF type calculations |
| suggested SOLUTIONS: |
| ) if not already the case, use automatic k-point generation |
| ) shift your grid to Gamma (G) (e.g. required for hex or fcc lattice) |
```

You need to define/use a correct k-point path.

As you already state that you can not use automatic k-point generation, the solution is:

- Identify the crystal symmetry you are working on.
- Look for the Brillouin zones of that symmetry.
- Select the high symmetry points for the path.
- Generate the k-point between each symmetry points.

Take o look [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6360/24) about how to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Previously, I did the band structure calculation for this same crystal system with the PBE functional through the VASP code. In that previous band structure calculation, I used high-symmetry k point and the calculation was done successfully. After that, I re-did this calculation with the HSE06 hybrid functional and I used the high-symmetry k point, which I used in the previous calculation with PBE functional. I do not understand why the high-symmetry k point does not work in the calculation with HSE06 hybrid functional...

Comment: ...while works in the calculation with PBE functional. Would you please give me more suggestions on the solution?  (Reproduced from Kieran's comment since it got too long).

Comment: I really don't know expect such behavior.  My only recommendation is to use a clean folder with the input files only and run the calculation again.

Answer (score 4):

This is an older question, but I faced something similar. Not sure if what I'm about to say applies to this case, but it might be a useful to have a record of this as a possible thing to troubleshoot for, for anybody who stumbles upon this post with similar issues.

Having followed similar steps as OP and got a similarly strange looking band structure, I found out my mistake was that I did not change the number of k-points on the second line of the `KPOINTS` file (it was left as the original number in the `IBZKPT` file). It should have been that value plus the number of zero-weighted k-points in the band structure path that was appended to the renamed `IBZKPT`->`KPOINTS` file. What my band structure plot showed was a 'k-path' through a uniform k-point mesh rather than through the desired high-symmetry k-point path.

I noticed my mistake upon a closer look at

1. VASP Wiki's [KPOINTS](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/KPOINTS) page, under "*Explicit k-point mesh*" where it specifies "*Provide the number of k points on the second line.*"
2. VASP Wiki's [HSE](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Si_bandstructure) band structure tutorial, in the `KPOINTS` file under "*Procedure 2: 0-weight (Fake) SC procedure (PBE & Hybrids)*", where they explicitly put the number of k-points as the number of weighted k-points that form a mesh, and the zero-weighted k-points on the high-symmetry path for band structure plotting. (The `IBZKPT` file from a previous regular-meshed k-point calculation only has the number of mesh k-points in its second line)